# Query to get max result from the output of other query

Tags: mysql

I used the query:

```
select count(registration.stu_id) as cnt,course.dept_id from registration,course where registration.course_id=course.course_id group by registration.course_id, course.dept_id
```

from this query I got the result:

```
cnt   | dept_id
2     |  1
1     |  3
1     |  2
1     |  4
1     |  5
```

Now i need to find out the result with max cnt

what query should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query if you want to get top 1 highest value

select count(registration.stu_id) as cnt,course.dept_id from registration,course where registration.course_id=course.course_id group by registration.course_id, course.dept_id
**order by cnt desc limit 1**

Avoid using of subqueries as much as possible for better performance..

Comment: limit is not supported in ms sql server

Comment: Yes limit is not supported in sql server, you can instead use top keyword. You tagged this question in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (
select count(registration.stu_id) as cnt,course.dept_id 
from registration,course where registration.course_id=course.course_id group 
by registration.course_id, course.dept_id ) 
y
```

You can use your query as a subquery then get the max

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select max(cnt) as max_cnt
from (select count(registration.stu_id) as cnt,
             course.dept_id 
      from registration,course 
      where registration.course_id=course.course_id 
      group by registration.course_id, course.dept_id)
```